# Optimal solution in Duplex simplex method

Tags: optimization, simplex

[I don't know what is the direct translation to English but it should be duplex simplex method]

we have a problem:

$$\min(z_k)=-2x_1+7x_2$$
$$x_1+x_2-x_4=2$$
$$2x_1+7x_2=3$$
$$x_i \geq 0$$
After some computation I get it to the final form:

$$\max(W)=2\Pi + 4\Pi + 3\Pi$$
$$x_{1} \rightarrow \Pi_{1}+\Pi_{3} \leq -2$$
$$x_{2} \rightarrow \Pi_{1}+\Pi_{2} -2 \Pi_{3} \leq 7$$
$$x^{-}_{3} \rightarrow -\Pi_{3} \leq 3$$
$$x^{+}_{3} \rightarrow +\Pi_{3} \leq -3$$
$$x^{-}_{4} \rightarrow -\Pi_{1} \leq 0$$
$$x^{-}_{5} \rightarrow -\Pi_{2} \leq 0$$
So after that there is a table solution:
\begin{array}{c|c}
 x_{B}&c_{b} b& x_{1} & x_{2} & x^{+}_{3} & x^{-}_{3} & x_{4}& x_{5} & x_{6} &  \\ 
  \hline
  x_{6} & M & & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 &2 \\
  \hline
  x_{5} & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &0 & 1 & 0 & 4 \\
  \hline
  x^{-}_{3} & -3 & 1 & -2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
  \hline
  && 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 \\
  \hline
  & &-1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -2
 \end{array}

Questions:

- What is the proper name of this simplex method?
- In which cases do we use the $x^{-}_{3}$ and $x^{+}_{3}$? What is the rule?
- How do we calculate the *last two rows*, the formula should be $\Pi^{*}=c^{T}_{B}*B^{-1}$ but I don't understand what should actually be done.

Comment: Dual Simplex Method.